# where can I find "imagick.so" for for ImageMagick 6.9.0.0 x86_64?

Tags: php, centos, imagemagick, imagick

I am not a Linux User.

I recently install ImageMagick on a CentOS via this tutorial:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-imagemagick-on-centos-6

Seems everything installed normally...

But After install,It seems I do not have "imagick.so" in my server...

I got this error with '`php -m | grep imagick`' command:

> PHP warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic liberary
>   '/usr/local/php54/lib/php/extentions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0

Also I search by `locate imagick.so` and couldn't find any file.

Also `convert --version`, It return me the version 6.9.0.0 Q16 X86_64

But I couldn't run any of this code:

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php

---

Now the question:

Is there a "imagick.so" file to download it to the server myself?

for example there are a lot of dll file for windows with same error...

How can I solve this problem?

I am on a VPS (centOS6.5/php5.4)

-----------------------Edit

I typed: `locate imagick.so`

the result:

> /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so
>
> usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.5.4/modules-Q16/coders/magick.so

then I try run: `sudo /usr/bin/pecl install imagick`

the result:

> Php warning: PHP Startup:Unable to load dynamic liberay
>   '/usr/lib64/modules/imagick.so' - /usr/lib64/modules/imagick.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unkown on
>   line 0 
>   .
>   .
>   . Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation
>   [autodetect] :

can help me more what can I to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can install imagick extesion with php pecl.

Open your terminal and execute:

```
sudo /usr/bin/pecl install imagick

sudo echo "extension=imagick.so" > /etc/php.d/imagick.ini

sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

After you can test, if was installed correct:

```
sudo php -m | grep imagick
```

Comment: pls, read here https://community.webfaction.com/questions/13537/installing-imagemagick-and-imagick-php-pecl-extension

Answer (score 0):

This is what I followed and helped me resolve this issue. Hope this helps to everyone. We need to remove old Imagick and install new with this procedure. [Link Imagick](http://ray.mindcola.com/getting-imagick-imagemagick-php-5-4-play-nice-centos-6-5/)