# make: *** [imagick.lo] Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed

Tags: php, makefile, imagemagick, centos6, imagick

I would like to install imagick in our Production server. There is cent Os install and I would like to install imagemagick as linux plugins and php extension but when I tried to install using command or event using whm I got following error. can anyone have solution for this question.

**I followed links :**

http://www.tecmint.com/install-imagemagick-in-linux/

http://crybit.com/how-to-install-imagemagick/

**Command line Output:**

```
root@wb01-development [/usr/local]# convert --versionVersion: ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2015-07-23 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

**Installation Log:**

```
root@wb01-development [/usr/local]# pecl install imagick 
downloading imagick-3.3.0.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.3.0.tgz (179,978 bytes)
......................................done: 179,978 bytes
17 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] : 
building in /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0
running: /root/tmp/pear/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-imagick
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable the imagick extension... yes, shared
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... found in /usr/bin/MagickWand-config
checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... found version 6.7.2 Q16
checking for MagickWand.h or magick-wand.h header... /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h
checking PHP version is at least 5.1.3... yes. found 5.5.30
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick   -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_file.c -o imagick_file.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_file.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_file.o
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_file.c: In function ‘php_imagick_is_url’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_file.c:85: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘php_stream_locate_url_wrapper’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/local/include/php/main/php_streams.h:552: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘const char **’
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick   -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c -o imagick_class.lo
 cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_class.o
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimagematte’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:295: warning: ‘MagickGetImageMatte’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:82)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_paintfloodfillimage’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:1204: warning: ‘MagickPaintFloodfillImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:99)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:1212: warning: ‘MagickPaintFloodfillImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:99)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_recolorimage’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:1673: warning: ‘MagickRecolorImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:109)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_colorfloodfillimage’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:3951: warning: ‘MagickColorFloodfillImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:75)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_mapimage’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:4369: warning: ‘MagickMapImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:86)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_mattefloodfillimage’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:4408: warning: ‘MagickMatteFloodfillImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:88)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_medianfilterimage’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:4444: warning: ‘MagickMedianFilterImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:212)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_paintopaqueimage’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:4524: warning: ‘MagickPaintOpaqueImageChannel’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:104)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_painttransparentimage’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:4605: warning: ‘MagickPaintTransparentImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:107)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_reducenoiseimage’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:4767: warning: ‘MagickReduceNoiseImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:260)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimageattribute’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:5935: warning: ‘MagickGetImageAttribute’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:59)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimagechannelextrema’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:6139: warning: ‘MagickGetImageChannelExtrema’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:78)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimageextrema’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:6413: warning: ‘MagickGetImageExtrema’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:80)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimageindex’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:7383: warning: ‘MagickGetImageIndex’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:65)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_setimageindex’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:7408: warning: ‘MagickSetImageIndex’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:113)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimagesize’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:7493: warning: ‘MagickGetImageSize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:140)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_setimageattribute’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:7910: warning: ‘MagickSetImageAttribute’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:111)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_flattenimages’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:8225: warning: ‘MagickFlattenImages’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:132)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_averageimages’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:9381: warning: ‘MagickAverageImages’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:131)
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_mosaicimages’:
/root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_class.c:9873: warning: ‘MagickMosaicImages’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:135)
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick   -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagickdraw_class.c -o imagickdraw_class.lo
 cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagickdraw_class.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/imagickdraw_class.o
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick   -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagickpixel_class.c -o imagickpixel_class.lo
 cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagickpixel_class.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/imagickpixel_class.o
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick   -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagickpixeliterator_class.c -o imagickpixeliterator_class.lo
 cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagickpixeliterator_class.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/imagickpixeliterator_class.o
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick   -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_helpers.c -o imagick_helpers.lo
 cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick_helpers.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_helpers.o
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick   -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick.c -o imagick.lo
 cc -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootJxIgP5/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/imagick -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/imagick.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27,
                 from /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick.c:31:
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/local/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27,
                 from /root/tmp/pear/imagick/imagick.c:31:
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre’
make: *** [imagick.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got my answer after refer following link:

[where can I find "imagick.so" for for ImageMagick 6.9.0.0 x86_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649232/where-can-i-find-imagick-so-for-for-imagemagick-6-9-0-0-x86-64)

> Open your terminal and execute:

```
sudo /usr/bin/pecl install imagick

sudo echo "extension=imagick.so" > /etc/php.d/imagick.ini

sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

> After you can test, if was installed correct:

```
sudo php -m | grep imagick
```

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't with Imagick, it appears there is something screwy with your PHP installation:

```
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/local/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27,
```

I'm guessing maybe you are trying to install it against an ancient version of PHP before the SPL and PCRE were included in the core code?

Either way, you need to find out more information about what PHP is installed on that box.